# Pure Functions In JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

For some unknown reason, I can't get object spread to work in my code. I'm having to fall back on 'Object.assign()', but would rather use '...'

The following works:

```
const frederick = {
  name: 'Frederick Douglass',
  canRead: false,
  canWrite: false
};

// create new object and mutate that one
const selfEducate = person =>
  Object.assign({}, person,
    {canRead:true},
    {canWrite:true}
  );

console.log(selfEducate(frederick));  // { name: 'Frederick Douglass', canRead: true, canWrite: true }
console.log(frederick);  // { name: 'Frederick Douglass', canRead: false, canWrite: false }
```

However, the following does not:

```
const frederick = {
  name: 'Frederick Douglass',
  canRead: false,
  canWrite: false
};

const selfEducate = person =>
  ({
    ...person,
    canRead: true,
    canWrite: true
  });

console.log(selfEducate(frederick));
console.log(frederick);
```

That one errors out with:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

The spread operator does work in other code of mine that involves copying arrays, but not in this example. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: In object literals, it's an upcoming feature (most likely) and isn't supported in most implementations. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-object_spread_properties

Comment: At which browser are you trying `javascript` at Question?

Comment: ES7 on this is a misnomer. ES7 is out and done, and ES8 is _almost_ out and done. Object spread like this is still a proposal, though it could end up in ES9.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: That's why I prefer using ES20XX to refer to recent versions (i.e. ES2016, ES2017).

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your other parts of code are working with the spread operator against arrays, that's not the same as trying to spread an object literal.

There's proposals for the spec to have it, such as [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps.

**Installation**

npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread

**Usage in existing presets**

"plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]

Reference link: [Click here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

NB: The object spread operator is not a default feature. It requires transpiler as above.